# How to close/open angular-ui bootstrap accordion programatically - within the js file

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui

Firstly, a similar question has been answered before, however the aforementioned does not resolve my issue.

I'd like to - from within my js, not within my html - be able to close the current accordion and open the next. Please note that this action will be triggered from the js from within a controller which is not the accordion controller (yes, I can use a factory function and make $scope available to other controllers, which I'm doing already). Also important is that the accordions are hard-coded so, they're not within a loop.

EDIT: Adding code

Ok, on my accordionCtrl is empty (at the moment as I don't need to add any code it for now), so all the action is happening on another controller:

```
    var CustomerFormCtrl = function($scope, mainObj, $http, $timeout) {

    $scope.saveCustomer = true;

    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.update = function(customer) {

        $scope.master = angular.copy(customer);
        mainObj.customer[customer.name] = customer;

        // Saving customer
        if($scope.saveCustomer === true) {

            $http({

                method: 'POST',
                url: '/customers/create',
                data: $.param(mainObj.customer),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

            })
            .success(function(data) {

                $scope.SavedCustomer = true;
                $scope.Message = "Customer saved";

                $timeout(function() { $scope.SavedCustomer = false }, 2000);

            });

        }

    };

    $scope.reset = function() {

        $scope.customer = angular.copy($scope.master);

    };

    $scope.reset();

}
```

And here's my accordion (in jade rather than html)

```
div(ng-controller="accordionCtrl")

    accordion(close-others="false")

        // Customer accordion
        accordion-group(heading="Step 1 - Customer details" is-open="true")

            div.col-md-6

                h4 Search a customer

                div(class="container-fluid", ng-controller="SearchCustomerCtrl")

                    input(type="text", ng-model="asyncSelected", placeholder="Search customer", typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control")
                    i(ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh")

            div.col-md-6

                h4 Customer details

                div(ng-controller="CustomerFormCtrl")

                    div(ng-show="SavedCustomer")

                        alert(type="success") {{Message}}

                    form(name="CustomerDetails", class="", role="form", novalidate)

                        div.form-group

                            // my form here

        // Order accordion
        accordion-group(heading="Step 2 - Placing the order")

            p Order

        // Checkout accordion
        accordion-group(heading="Step 3 - Checkout")

            p Checkout
```

On `$http({...}).success(function(data) {...}` I'd like to add some code that'd close the Step 1 accordion and open Step 2.

If I was using jQuery (which I can do, but I'd rather not) I could select the aforementioned accordion through it' id/class something along these lines:

```
$('.boot-tab').find('li.active')
                .next()
                .find('a[data-toggle="tab"]')
                .click();
```

But with Angular I've no idea how to make this work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there any code we can see, like an attempt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - the easiest way is instead of setting `is-open` to true, set it to a property on your scope.

```
accordion-group(heading="Step 1 - Customer details" is-open="$parent.step1open")
```

if you want to, you can put the init inline there too:

```
accordion-group(heading="Step 1 - Customer details" is-open="$parent.step1open" ng-init="step1open = false")
```

Then in your JS, set `$scope.step1open = true` in your success function.  I assume you're doing this in the `accordianCtl` - if you're not, you'll soon have followup questions about scope visiblity and inheritance.

Here's [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BcWDIaSvTP1BCsqvGTxN?p=preview) with an example.

Comment: Hi Philip. I did try as said, having changed the controller so everything now is within accordionCtrl to avoid using `$broadcast` but unfortunately it doesn't work. I got         `$scope.step1 = true; $scope.step2 = false; $scope.step3 = false;` at the beginning of my controller and `$scope.step2 = true` in my success function. If I `console.log($scope.step2)` it'll log true, but nothing happens with the accordion. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a Plunker (or similar)?  Actual code goes a long way.

Comment: Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WvLvnoGt5wmCFcYXPh1i?p=preview) I've created. You'll notice that I've added `$scope.step1 = true` at the beginning of my controller. In this plunker, all accordions start (after loading page) closed, however on my local machine, the first accordion starts open (as expected as I've set the step1 to true.

Comment: See the plunker I forked from yours (linked in the answer).  Yours had two problems: First no ng-controller listed.  And the second and less obvious is that the accordian creates a nested scope - that's why you see the `$parent.step1` rather than just `step1`.

Comment: Hi Philip. Unfortunately still didn't work. Yes, in my plunker I did miss the controller, but in my code was there. I've tried your suggestion but still doesn't work. If I do $scope.$parent.step1 = true and log this, I can see the value has changed, yet the accordion won't open. I've updated my plunker so it has all of my code. Btw, thanks for your help. Much appreciated!

Comment: The plunkr you have doesn't work because the controller is not still not there, and even if update contains imports that don't exist in the plunker.    If you look [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BcWDIaSvTP1BCsqvGTxN?p=preview) you can see how it can work.   Note that the `$parent` portion I mentioned is in the HTML, not in the controller code.

Comment: @Philp thank you! Like I said, on my code the controller was there. The problem was that I added the `$parent` in the controller rather than in the html. Does it work the same in all UI directives or just the accordion one?

Comment: The theory is the same, but each UI directive is different.  However, *many* will create a nested scope.  I recommend getting a developer plugin like the [Angular Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) to help you find scope nesting until you feel comfortable reading the directive's source to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issues with the accepted answer so for anyone else that's still having trouble let me help.  Here is a way to not only programatically show the content, but also programatically show/hide increments of the groups, kind of like pagination.

Here's a quick example accordion:
`<accordion close-others="false">
            <accordion-group ng-repeat="item in myAjaxedItems" is-open="accordionIndexViewable($index)">
                 ... some accordion content / heading / what-have-you
            </accordion-group>
</accordion>`

Notice the `"accordionIndexViewable"` function.  You can pass the index of the accordion's ng-repeat using the `$index` variable.  Then check if that index should be viewable based on some other scope "viewable item limit".  You can have a "Show more" button that in this case would call some other function to increment the "viewable item limit".

And here's the controller:
    `myApp.controller('MyCustomAccordionController', function($scope){
         $scope.itemLimit = 1;
         $scope.accordionIndexViewable = function(index){
             return index < $scope.itemLimit;
         };
         // another function which will trigger on some event to change the itemLimit.  Can do a variety of different things for paginating down/up.  But in this case it's super simple.
         $scope.onClickingSomething = function() {
             if($scope.itemLimit <= 10)
                 $scope.itemLimit += 2;
         };
    });`

The is-open attribute may not be desirable on the actual model item itself.  For me, there was an update taking place on the model (via ajax) and I didn't want an "open" property on the actual DB model item.  The `accordionIndexViewable` function is a good alternative and idempotent.  There could even be a more efficient way of doing it using an object hashmap, but that's beyond being necessary to answer this question here.